# Administrator account prevents me from reverting Windows 10 to 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, administrator, windows-10

On Windows 10, I had to enable the Administrator account using

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

for reasons that aren't relevant here.

Now, if I try to revert to Windows 8.1 through Settings >> Update & Security >> Recovery >> Go back to Windows 8.1, I get the following message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp280.png]

But there is no other user, including Administrator, visible on the Other Users screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcFaK.png]

I did

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

to deactivate the Administrator account (because the Administrator account is always existent, just that it can be disabled or enabled). After that I double-checked that the Administrator account is disabled in `lusrmgr.msc` and not visible in `netplwiz.exe`, but I still keep getting the message in the first picture.

What could be wrong? Any ideas? I really want to roll back to 8.1.

Comment: Try moving the `c:\users\administrator` folder to somewhere safe and see if that helps.  Also try adding a user account and then deleting it.  Or you might need to remove the administrator profile from the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.  The Administrator profile ends in -500.  Make sure you use right-click/Export to make a backup first.

Comment: ... now that I think of it, it might be sensible to ask this question in Microsoft's support forums as well as here.

Answer (score 6):

#### Administrator account prevents Windows 10 rollback

Use **one** of the solutions below and then try again to rollback.

---

#### Solution 1

> 1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `sysdm.cpl` andpress <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. Click on "Advanced" tab.
> 3. Click on "Settings"  under the "User Profiles" section.
> 4. On the "User Profiles" dialog select the `<COMPUTER NAME>\Administrator account` and click  on "Delete".
> 5. Confirm the delete.
>
> Warning:
>
> The above steps will also delete all data associated with the built-in
>   Administrator account – please ensure data associated with the
>   built-in Admin is backed up prior to performing the steps.

Source [Roll Back of Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/roll-back-of-windows-10/2a669c0f-4dfb-4ef6-8118-f0faba6e298e)

---

#### Solution 2

> Please go to the registry editor and do the following steps:
>
> 1. Click <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, to open run command. Type "regedit" and click enter.
> 2. Create a back of the registry. Click on Hkey and go to the File Tab, press Export and save it to your desired your location.
> 3. Go to the provided path `HKey_LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
> 4. In the profile list you will find a few SID's please find the one related to the deleted user account and delete it.
>
> To know which sid is related to the User Account you wish to delete
>   just go to a particular `S-1-5` series and on the right side look for
>   ProfileImagePath, you will notice `c:/users/User_Account_Name`.

Source [Go back to Windows 7 with User account issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/go-back-to-windows-7-with-user-account-issue/63e30e33-0664-4810-8c73-5cc0c38225e4?auth=1)

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly. You are a life saver.

Comment: Fantastic post. Great information.