# Cannot restore Windows 8 from Windows 10 because of local administrator account

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I once activated local administrator account with net user. When trying to go back to windows 8 it refused because it said administrator account had been created. So I use net user again to deactivate local admin account (/activate:no) which executed successfully. Still it still refuses to go back.

Why, What can I do ?

Comment: Why the negative :(

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but it's probably because your question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Relevant: [Administrator account prevents me from reverting Windows 10 to 8.1](http://superuser.com/q/950288)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve : I thought it's clear enough downgrade to windows 8

Answer (score 1):

#### Administrator account prevents Windows 10 rollback

Use **one** of the solutions below and then try again to rollback.

---

#### Solution 1

> 1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `sysdm.cpl` andpress <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. Click on "Advanced" tab.
> 3. Click on "Settings"  under the "User Profiles" section.
> 4. On the "User Profiles" dialog select the `<COMPUTER NAME>\Administrator account` and click  on "Delete".
> 5. Confirm the delete.
>
> Warning:
>
> The above steps will also delete all data associated with the built-in
>   Administrator account – please ensure data associated with the
>   built-in Admin is backed up prior to performing the steps.

Source [Roll Back of Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/roll-back-of-windows-10/2a669c0f-4dfb-4ef6-8118-f0faba6e298e)

---

#### Solution 2

> Please go to the registry editor and do the following steps:
>
> 1. Click <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, to open run command. Type "regedit" and click enter.
> 2. Create a back of the registry. Click on Hkey and go to the File Tab, press Export and save it to your desired your location.
> 3. Go to the provided path `HKey_LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
> 4. In the profile list you will find a few SID's please find the one related to the deleted user account and delete it.
>
> To know which sid is related to the User Account you wish to delete
>   just go to a particular `S-1-5` series and on the right side look for
>   ProfileImagePath, you will notice `c:/users/User_Account_Name`.

Source [Go back to Windows 7 with User account issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/go-back-to-windows-7-with-user-account-issue/63e30e33-0664-4810-8c73-5cc0c38225e4?auth=1)