# How do I Uninstall Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I know this has been asked but I don't see any answers, just comments on the form of the question or responses that don't seem to speak my language.

I unintentionally (yes, I meant to use that word) installed Windows 10 on a HP desktop.  Since then I can't open web pages, can't print my calendar, some programs don't work while others only function on a part time basis and many other glitches that prevent me from doing my work.

After the install I saw a message that said the old files would remain for 30 days then be deleted.  I presumed that meant I could switch back.  I can't continue to function without a computer.

Comment: @Ramhound the `Windows.old` folder that has the files from the previous OS is deleted after 30 days of using Windows 10. Just a small tidbit about being able to rollback to the previous version.

Comment: @DrZoo - I am more then aware of that.  Why did you feel the need to ping me to tell me that?

Comment: @Ramhound because you didn't state that in your comment. I was making sure you and the person who asked the question was aware of that so it wouldn't create more questions. If you knew it, you should of stated it so they wouldn't be confused if their rollback doesn't work.

Comment: @DrZoo - I couldn't list all the things I should have said in a single comment due to length, given a duplicate already exists, I don't feel the need to come back.

Answer (score 5):

#### How do I go back (roll back) to the previous version of Windows?

Notes:

- The procedure below will only work for 30 days after the upgrade to Windows 10.
- After 30 days the `windows.old` folder is automatically removed, which will prevent the rollback from succeeding.

> For a month after you upgrade to Windows 10, you’ll be able to go back
>   to your previous version of Windows from `Settings` > `Update & security`> `Recovery`.

[image]

Choose "Go Back to Windows 8.1" or "Go Back to Windows 7" as appropriate ( depending on your original operating system), and Windows will begin the rollback procedure.

> This will keep your personal files, but it'll remove apps and drivers installed after the upgrade, as well as any changes you
>   made to settings. To go back, you'll need to:
>
> - Keep everything in the `windows.old` and `$windows.~bt` folders after the upgrade.
> - Remove any user accounts you added after the upgrade.
> - Know the password you used to sign in to Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 (if you used one).
> - Have the USB drive you used to upgrade to Windows 10 (if you used one).
>
> Note
>
> - If you go back to Windows 8.1, some apps that came with Windows, like Mail and People, might not work anymore. To fix them, reinstall
>     them from the Store.

Source [Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

---

If you have problems rolling back because of an Administrator account that cannot be removed, please see [Administrator account prevents Windows 10 rollback](https://superuser.com/a/965144/337631).